# Schengen Visa Change or Edit the itinerary possible?

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas

My Friend has again a Schengen Visa this Time Type C 60 Days Two Entries. Remarks Visit & VIS stands on the Sticker

2 Schengen Countries to Visit

First entry is already over exactly like in the itinerary.
Is it possible to change the split of the Days at the second entrie like stay longer in one country and less in the other?
Arrival Airport is the Country who issued the Visa after a couple of days he  go forward to the other Countrylike in the itinerary.

The Immigration see the Exactly itinerary on the Computer?

Comment: How big is the difference? 10-8 days to 8-10 days or 80-2 days to 2-80 days.

Comment: First entry was 12-10 already over. In the itinerary the second entry 16-13 but he get from the Embassy 9 more Days approved  then in the Application requested so maybe its possible the second entry 16-22 or 14-24 ?

Comment: Anybody an Idea?